# iOS, how to detect the user pull down the list beyond the first row?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a list that has rows of pictures, I want the functionality that, when user pulls down the list(use the finger to slide down the list, causing the first row being down for a while and bouncing to top) I refresh the list.

How to detect user is pull down the list beyond the first row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why work so hard?
http://cocoacontrols.com/controls/pull-to-refresh-tableview

Answer (score 3):

Implement scrollViewDidScroll: on the delegate and check for negative contentOffset.  And @stavash is right, there's some net code that can help, too.